# Styling ul tag and li tags without effects others ul and li

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue about styling `ul` and `li`... I gave class because other ul li taking effects of new styles. But my classes not running properly.

```css
.filter ul {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-top: 6px solid #4b7bec;
  border-left: 1px solid #273c75;
  border-right: 1px solid #273c75;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 750px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.filter .filter-sec > li {
  width: 33.3%;
  border-right: 1px solid #273c75;
  float: left;
}

#no-border {
  border-right: 0;
}

.filter .filter-sec > li a {
  display: block;
  color: #273c75;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.filter .filter-sec li a:hover {
  background-color: #44bd32;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="filter">
              <li class="filter-sec"><a href="#">one</a></li>
              <li class="filter-sec"><a href="#">two</a></li>
              <li class="filter-sec" id="no-border"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
```

what I am I doing wrong here?  Why css is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misplacing `.filter ul` note that a `.` is a class selector. If you want to select an `<ul>` with `filter` class then you should use `ul.filter`

Also for selecting `<li>` you're also targeting the wrong one.

Example: `.filter .filter-sec > li a` would be better if you do `.filter li.filter-sec > a` since you're targeting a `.filter` class then an `<li>` with `.filter-sec` class then you're targeting `<a>`

More info about CSS Selector [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Check the following snippet:

```css
ul.filter {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-top: 6px solid #4b7bec;
  border-left: 1px solid #273c75;
  border-right: 1px solid #273c75;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 750px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.filter li.filter-sec {
  width: 33.3%;
  border-right: 1px solid #273c75;
  float: left;
}

#no-border {
  border-right: 0;
}

.filter li.filter-sec > a {
  display: block;
  color: #273c75;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.filter li.filter-sec > a:hover {
  background-color: #44bd32;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="filter">
              <li class="filter-sec"><a href="#">one</a></li>
              <li class="filter-sec"><a href="#">two</a></li>
              <li class="filter-sec" id="no-border"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```